# Во время запроса на доступ к галлереи на заднем плане подсвечивается вьюха.

Tags: ios, swift

два положения запроса доступа к галлереи, первое это когда пользователь зареган, то я обхожу экран с предложением подписки и на фоне черный экран. Все норм:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второе, когда юзер не зареган, сразу же предлагаем экран подписки(регистрации), затем я тапаю пропустить и регаюсь через экран логирования дальше хочу получить доступ к галлереи и вот что выходит на фоне:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я не понимаю экран подписки вышел из стека экранов, почему он висит?

Вот иерархия первого состояния (нормального):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот иерархия когда на фоне экран регистрации.:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй презентить ImagePickerController поверх текущего контекста 
imagePickerController.presentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

Comment: спасибо большое!